# I'm using QoS on my router (gargoyle), but still experiencing lag

Tags: networking, router, qos

I've installed gargolye on my TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v9 router. This is my current configuration for quality of service (192.168.1.245 is the static IP for my computer). The problem is, I still experience lag/ping spikes when someone else on the network is watching youtube. The game I'm trying to protect from lag is league of legends. Do you see anything wrong in my settings? Could there be some other source of lag that need to be addressed?

upload:

[image]

---

download:

[image]

Comment: What's your actual speed test up down? You need to put your max speeds about 10% lower then what the speed test shows. The idea of qos is that your creating a bottle neck on your side of the network to ensure you have control over traffic, not the ISP routers

Comment: Run something like ping or pingplot for a day to a well-known reliable site, and see what your ping times do.  If there are very high pings in the middle of low ones, there is a problem somewhere.  Try a different cable, different router, don't be on wifi, etc.  Isolate the problem to where it is, then solve that problem.

Comment: Ah, I think the problem might've been that I assumed the test results were in megabytes, rather than in megabits. Speedtest.net gives me an average of 15.3 Mbps, so the total download bandwidth should be 15300 kilobits, rather than what I have.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a speed test, depending on your connection type. You want to do the speed test with no other users or devices on the network and you want to do it at peak times. This is to make sure you get an accurate reading. if you put the wrong info in the total bandwidth boxes, it will most likely make the connection worse.

From your comment, download = 15.3Mbps - 10% = 13.77Mbps (13770 kbps)
So 13770kbps is what you would put for download. you need to do the same with upload.

There is a couple things I noticed that are wrong with your config:

1. The default upload/download service class is set to normal. you want this set to low/slowest, as it acts as a catch all for any service that hasn't been specified.
2. You have HTTP/HTTPS set as normal priority with a maximum of 1024KBps(1 MBps or 8Mbps) in both upload/download but then in service class have normal set to 38% of your available bandwidth. The max of 1024KBps is more like half of the available bandwidth, if the speed test in your comment is accurate.
3. You have DNS in the slow queue, you most likely want this in the fast queue.
   If you don't, when under heavy load all browsing activity will seem like clicking links/redirects become unbearably slow. depending on how your game communicates to peers it could also bring lag to online play.
4. Readjust your service class percentages after you know for sure what your total upload and download is.

Happy Gaming ;)

Comment: @nightfire if this has answered your question please consider marking as answered so other people will find it in their searches. If you are still having problems with it just send a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Doing upload QoS is almost easy. Downstream QoS can be quite hard. The problem is, you need QoS classification and prioritization to happen at/before the choke point.

Unless replies to your packets are QoS marked and your internet service provider honors the QoS markings (maybe, but I haven't seen it), packets from the internet to you can get delayed/stuck on the ISP side.

You can't exactly instruct all of the other computers on the internet how much to send so as to have no queues and full pipes, but if you limit your download even more than your ISP does, the queues would form on your equipment where you can prioritize what you want and the other tcp connections should more or less behave themselves by reducing speed when packets are dropped and thus not create huge spikes. Also beware of bufferbloat - make sure you have small buffers/queues and drop packets early.

On a quick glance, you upload setting seam ok, but unless you actually have more than 122Mbit/s sustained download bandwidth from your ISP, your download QoS effectively does nothing (may affect wifi, but probably not what you want).